# Objective C - Can't set superclass property in subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties

Take this simple class hierarchy:

**Tree.h**:

```
@interface Tree : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TreeDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**Tree.m**:

```
@implementation Tree
@synthesize delegate;
@end
```

**Aspen.h**:

```
@interface Aspen : Tree
- (void)grow:(id<TreeDelegate>)delegate;
@end
```

**Aspen.m**:

```
@implementation Aspen
- (void) grow:(id<TreeDelegate>)d {
    self.delegate = d;
}
@end
```

When I try to do `self.delegate = d;`, I'm getting the following error:

> -[Aspen setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x586da00

I was expecting the `Tree` parent class's `delegate` property to be visible to the subclass as-is, but it doesn't seem to be since the error indicates the parent class's synthesized setter isn't visible.

What am I missing?  Do I have to redeclare the property at the subclass level?  I tried adding `@dynamic` at the top of the implementation of `Aspen` but that didn't work either.  Such a simple concept here, but I've lost an hour searching around trying to find a solution.  Out of ideas at this point.

**--EDIT--**

The above code is just a very stripped-down example to demonstrate the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: I think we're going to need the actual code - after fixing the `implmentation` typo for Aspen, this works fine for me.

Comment: @Tim Typo fixed, thanks. So - this should work as-is?

Comment: I can't post the actual code, but I've updated the example in my question to more closely reflect the actual source.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Your stripped-down version looks good to me. The problem is certainly going to be found in the code you removed while stripping this down.

Comment: @KevinBallard et al, thanks. I will take another look at what I have and try to post more.

Comment: @Madbreaks: The fundamental problem is `Aspen` does not respond to `-setDelegate:`. So either your superclass's property is readonly, or it has a different setter (e.g. `@property (setter=setFoo:) id delegate`), or maybe the property isn't actually declared on the class you think it is, or `Aspen` doesn't have the superclass you think it does, or something even more wacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out.  My actual code leverages a 3rd party static library that defines the classes `Tree` and `Aspen` in my example.  I had built a new version of the static library that exposed the `Tree delegate` given in my example, however I did not properly re-link the library after adding it to my project and as a result the old version was still being accessed at runtime.

Lessons learned: be diligent with steps to import a 3rd party library, and when simple fundamental programming concepts (such as in my example text) aren't working, take a step back and make sure you've dotted i's and crossed t's.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code, supplemented by the protocol, an object implementing it, the necessary `import` and a `main` function and on my system it works like a charm:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol TreeDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface MyDelegate : NSObject <TreeDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyDelegate
@end

@interface Tree : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TreeDelegate> delegate;
@end

@interface Aspen : Tree
- (void)grow:(id<TreeDelegate>)delegate;
@end

@implementation Tree
@synthesize delegate;
@end

@implementation Aspen
- (void) grow:(id<TreeDelegate>)d {
    self.delegate = d;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    MyDelegate * d = [[MyDelegate alloc] init];
    Aspen * a = [[Aspen alloc] init];

    [a grow:d];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, ok.  This at least confirms what I previously believed, that it *should* work this way.  I will take another look at my code and see if I can spot any differences from what you have here.